# IvoryCKEditorBundle + FMElfinderBundle

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, symfony-forms, elfinder

I'm trying to work with the [IvoryCKEditorBundle](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle)and [FMElfinderBundle](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle). The **IvoryCKEditorBundle** is a CKEditor and the **ElfinderBundle** is a finder to integrate images in my CKEditor.

The CKEditor works and is integrated in my form like this:

```
->add('articleBody', 'ckeditor',[
    'config' => [
        'toolbar' => [
            [
                'name'  => 'document',
                'items' => ['Source', '-', 'NewPage', 'DocProps', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates'],
            ],
            '/',
            [
                'name'  => 'basicstyles',
                'items' => ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'],
            ]
        ],
        'uiColor' => '#ffffff',
    ]])
```

Now I would like to integrate the finder. To integrate this you have to follow [these](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle#installation)steps. These are the steps that I have already done:

- Downloaded bundle
- Added to kernel
- Import FMElfinderBundle routing file
- Configure assetic
- Install and dump assets

But now I'm stuck at the Basic configuration. When I copy the code and paste it in my config.yml I get the following error:

> InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "instances" under "fm_elfinder"

What am I doing wrong?